# Get IO service time (svctm), wait time(await), %util in windows server

Tags: windows, command-line, io, command-line-interface

We get all these information in unix using iostat in UNIX. What can I do this in windows. Currently we use typeperf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every statistics that Windows has can be acessed using its Powershell API:

Get-Counter
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx

So, for example, if you do:

```
Set-Alias grep Select-String
(Get-Counter -List PhysicalDisk).PathsWithInstances | grep "C:"
```

you will get a list of all statistics for you C: drive

```
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Current Disk Queue Length
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\% Disk Time
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk Queue Length
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\% Disk Read Time
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\% Disk Write Time
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk sec/Read
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk sec/Write
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Disk Transfers/sec
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Disk Reads/sec
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Disk Writes/sec
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Disk Bytes/sec
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Disk Read Bytes/sec
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Disk Write Bytes/sec
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Read
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Write
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\% Idle Time
\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Split IO/Sec
```

From the man page of iostat (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iostat1.html)

```
svctm
    The  average  service  time  (in  milliseconds)  for  I/O
    requests that were issued to the device.
await
    The average  time  (in  milliseconds)  for  I/O  requests
    issued to the device to be served. This includes the time
    spent by the requests in queue and the time spent servicing them.
```

I am following these interpretations:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104192/iostat-await-vs-svctm
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/09/06/beware-of-svctm-in-linuxs-iostat/

Including the discussion that svctm should not be used anymore.

If you see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2012/02/07/measuring-disk-latency-with-windows-performance-monitor-perfmon/, you will see that Windows have something similar.

The counter named "\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer" measures the time spent on:
- Class Driver
- Port Driver
- Device Miniport Driver
- Disk Subsystem

So, for example we can monitor these statistics with:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\% Disk Time"
Get-Counter -Counter "\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer"
```

or if you prefer, the more "pipelined" version:

```
"\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\% Disk Time","\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer" >> counters.txt
cat counters.txt | Get-Counter
```

For a more detailed explanation of each counter see:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2012/03/16/windows-performance-monitor-disk-counters-explained/

Answer (score 1):

There is also a utility "logman".
Links on this topic:
Clint Huffman blog & book
http://blogs.technet.com/b/clinth/
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0124167012/ref=wl...=I2TOVTYHI6HDHC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124167012)